# Enumerating array in reverse order using size_t index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Let's say we need to print `int` array with size `N` in reverse order:

```
// Wrong, i is unsigned and always >= 0:
for(size_t i = N-1; i >= 0; --i){cout << data[i];}

// Correct, but uses int instead of size_t:
for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i){cout << data[i];}

// Correct, but requires additional operation in the loop:
for(size_t i = N; i > 0; --i){cout << data[i-1];}

// Probably the best version, but less readable.
// Is this well-defined behavior?
for(size_t i = N-1; i != (size_t)(-1); --i){cout << data[i];}
```

Is there better way to do such enumeration using `size_t` index and without additional operations in the loop?

Is it valid to assume that `(size_t)0 - 1` gives `(size_t)(-1)` or this is undefined?

Comment: If I *know* I'm going to iterate at least once then I use a `do` / `while`. Else I tend to count one-based and use `data[i - 1]`.

Comment: Why "using `size_t` index" over an itereator?

Comment: I suggest changing the code so that you use the index in the loop. Because I think it is a valid question, often you do need the index. Otherwise you will get side-tracked from the real question by valid suggestions to use an iterator or similar.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: right, I could prevent this side-tracking by tagging this question with C language and changing the code to C. But it is too late now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the decrement to "after" the condition.

```
for(size_t i = N; i > 0;) {
    --i;
    cout << data[i];
}
```

It's not as elegant as a forwards loop but it works. We break at 0 so `i` never wraps.

Answer (score 2):

since C++14:

```
for (auto it = std::rbegin(data); it != std::rend(data); ++it) { std::cout << *it; }
```

Or if you can use boost, you may use `boost::adaptors::reversed` and for range.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply test for `i < N`.

size_t is defined as an unsigned integer, which in turn is defined to have modulo semantics. So your index will go from `N-1` down to 0 and then wrap around to `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` for which `i<N` doesn't hold true any longer.
To give a full example:

```
for(size_t i = N-1; i < N; --i){cout << data[i];}
```

Comment: As you are doing `i = N-1;` and `--i;` so `i < N` will be true always. It will be like infinite loop.

Comment: @Himanshu No, this works. Rather, the problem with this solution is that some people will think it doesn't work.

Comment: I think this code is correct, it is similar to my last version `i != (size_t)(-1)` but looks more tricky.

Comment: @MikeMB u r correct. I thought may be it will work for 0,0,.. after reaching index 0.

Comment: @Alex I'd say it 'looks' simpler than your example, but as this discussion shows it might be easier to misinterpret and I'd say your version probably shows the intent more clearly. Basically you require the reader to understand either what a c-cast from signed to unsigned does or what a underflow of a unsigned int does. In the end it probably depends on which notation you are more used to.

Comment: I like this solution. It works well if you need to conditionally iterate forwards or backwards, starting from some given index. The invariant doesn't need to change, only the increment, which can just be `i += direction`